# NotifyDataSetChanged does not work in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use searchbar to sort some ArrayList and show result in RecyclerView.

According to log, Data seems to be filtered well, however filtered result is not appeared in RecyclerView.

I think this code should activate well...

What Should I do?

Here's my Activity codes :

```
class RegisterActivity_7_Taste : AppCompatActivity(), OnTasteClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding : LayoutRegisterTasteBinding

    var taste_list = ArrayList<String>()

    private lateinit var adapter : RecyclerViewAdapter_Taste

    var check_taste = ArrayList<String>()

    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("url")
    val ref = database.getReference("path")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = LayoutRegisterTasteBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val taste_string = getSharedPreferences("data_booster", 0).getString("taste", "failed")
        taste_list = taste_string!!.split(",").distinct() as ArrayList<String>

        val editor = getSharedPreferences("data_cloud", 0).edit()

        binding.tasteSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(searchViewTextListener)

        binding.tasteSelect.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter_Taste(taste_list, this)
        binding.tasteSelect.setAdapter(adapter)
    }

    var searchViewTextListener: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener =
        object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(s: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(s: String): Boolean {
                adapter.filter.filter(s)
                Log.d("RegisterActivity_8_Taste", "SearchView Text is Changed : $s")
                
                return false
            }
     }
}
```

And Here's my Adapter :

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter_Taste(private val taste_list : ArrayList<String>, private val listener : OnTasteClickListener)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter_Taste.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    inner class MyViewHolder(binding : FragmentRegisterTasteAdapterBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val btn = binding.btn
        val root = binding.root
    }

    var TAG = "TasteRecyclerViewAdapter"
    var filteredTaste = ArrayList<String>()
    var itemFilter = ItemFilter()

    init {
        filteredTaste.addAll(taste_list)
    }

    var check : Boolean = false

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val binding : FragmentRegisterTasteAdapterBinding =
            FragmentRegisterTasteAdapterBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val taste_name = taste_list[position].toString()

        holder.btn.text = taste_name

        holder.btn.setOnClickListener {
            if(check == false) {
                holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_main_color)
                listener.onTasteClickAdd(taste_name)
                check = true
            }
            else {
                holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_sub_color_light)
                listener.onTasteClickRemove(taste_name)
                check = false
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return taste_list.size
    }

    override fun getFilter() : Filter {
        return itemFilter
    }

    inner class ItemFilter : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(p: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filterString = p.toString()
            val results = FilterResults()
            Log.d(TAG, "charSequence : $p")

            val filteredList : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
            if(filterString.trim{it<= ' '}.isEmpty()) {
                results.values = taste_list
                results.count = taste_list.size
            }
            else {
                for (taste in taste_list) {
                    if (taste.contains(filterString)) {
                        filteredList.add(taste)
                    }
                }

                results.values = filteredList
                results.count = filteredList.size
            }

            return results
        }

        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun publishResults(p0: CharSequence?, p1: FilterResults) {
            filteredTaste.clear()
            filteredTaste.addAll(p1.values as ArrayList<String>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: remove this line  Log.d("

Comment: It's a mistake when I wrote this question...

Comment: https://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2020/09/android-recyclerView-data-list-filterable-kotlin.html

Comment: your code is not proper

Comment: so i refer this link